# How to use an input to print the info of a class [PYTHON 3]

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm not really sure how to phrase the question, but here's what i'm basically trying to do:

```
class pokemon:
    def __init__(self, info):
        self.info=info

treecko=pokemon("fido")

poke=input()
print(poke.info)
```

it's very clear what I'm trying to do, but when executed it doesn't work, however if i were to type into the shell:

```
treecko.info
```

of course it will display "fido". I want to make a large database listing the info of all pokemon, but have kept it as simple as i can for argument purposes. All I'm trying to find out is what is a simple way to get the input and stick it infront of ".info" to bring up the info of that pokemon input, so that any pokemon that is input will follow the same rules and display info. Please get back to me ASAP, thanks :)

Comment: it would be `print(eval(poke).info)` but there are better ways

Answer (score 1):

You could use `print(eval(poke).info)` but I would not recommend it, use a dict instead with instance names strings stored as keys, and instances stored as values:

```
class pokemon:
    def __init__(self, info):
        self.info=info

treecko=pokemon("fido")

poke = input() 
d = {"treecko":treecko}    
print(d[poke].info)
fido
```

If you wanted you could pass a name  to the constructor and have a class attribute dict that stores each instances name:

```
class pokemon:
    instances_d = {}
    def __init__(self, info, name):
        self.name = name
        self.info = info
        pokemon.instances_d[name] = self

treecko = pokemon("fido","treecko")


treecko = pokemon("fido","treecko")
treecko1 = pokemon("dido","treecko1")

poke = input()
print(pokemon.instances_d[poke].info)
poke = input()
print(pokemon.instances_d[poke].info)
treecko
fido
treecko1
dido
```